# Numpy: Creating an arbitrary view of an array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

To represent a Sudoku grid I have the following:

```
values = np.arange(81)
rows = values.reshape(9,9)
cols = rows.T
```

where `rows` and `cols` are views into `values`, allowing me to modify the `values` array in-place.

With the cells' indices in `values` and the `rows` view to visualize the grid, I have:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
       [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62],
       [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
       [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]])
```

In addition to having a `rows` and a `cols` view into the data, I also need a `blocks` view, where a block is defined by 3x3 squares on the grid.  For example, block zero contains the cell indices `[0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20]`, while block one has indices `[3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23]`, and so on.

I have tried concatenating views from slices, such as:

```
block = values[0:3] + values[9:12] + values[18:21]
```

but concatenating views always makes copies.

Further efforts were to use advanced indexing, but advanced indexing always returns copies:

```
block = values[[0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20]]
```

Finally,  I tried to use the `lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(x, ...)`, and `lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, [, shape, ...])`, but for the life of me couldn't see a way to get the view I need.  Furthermore, I have seen other questions and the documentation make mention that arbitrary views have the restriction of viewing only contiguous regions of memory.

This is a major bottleneck for my Sudoku solver and I can't afford to make copies every time I want to update the values through the block interface.  I do realize that a solution is to maintain a list of indices into the `values` array to represent each block and manually update the values, but I am trying to avoid this in the sake of efficiency.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: ```np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(values.reshape(9,9), (3,3))[::3,::3]``` should give you the blocks, but you shouldn't write to a strided view.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you very much.  This is exactly what I was trying to figure out.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: That is a great elegant solution for a sudoku solver!